# Error 500 on wordpress update and plugin pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't understand how to save an issue on a hosted worpdress installation.
My current wordpress version is 4.7 installed on linux hosting with mysql db.
Every time I access either wordpress update page or plugin update page I get a 500 error.

With some debugging I've narrowed down the issue to the file `admin.php` and precisely line 329:

```
do_action( "load-{$pagenow}" );
```

I really can't figure out what the problem is!

Comment: We can't really figure it out either because we can't really read the logs you didn't provide :)

Comment: I wish I could provide any. But I don't have any error on logs apart this 500 error displayed on browser.

Comment: In your `wp-config.php` enable debugging - `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` Then after it add `ini_set('log_errors',TRUE); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');` Then you'll have `error_log.txt` file where your `wp-config.php` file is. This will help you narrow the issue down...

Comment: uhm done with no luck...and no logs.

Answer (score 0):

In your wp-config.php if you enable debugging (just find WP_DEBUG and set it to true)

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Then you should be able to see the error. If not, there would be error logs on your cpanel where you can see the errors. Also look for files named 'error_log' inside your WordPress installation.